# MultiBinding and ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding, contentpresenter

This is my code of `ContentPresenter`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ValueContainer">
            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding Path="ReadOnly"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ContentPresenter.Content>
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=Content.ReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=Content.Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                                TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I trying to fill the `Text` from object `Items.Value` and property `IsReadOnly` from `Items.ReadOnly`.

It doesn't work, I know that is not good solution, but, how to make something like that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: have you tried to add relativeSource to your Listbox ?
if it not works, use button whereas textbox and pur relativeSource at Command property and the content at Text Property

Comment: Fill the `Text` from object `Items.Value` and property `IsReadOnly` from `Items.ReadOnly`

Comment: @angel I didn't tried to add relativeSource. I don't understand how it to do:( How it help me?

Comment: `<SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedChoice, Mode=TwoWay}"> // add selectedindex at listbox


    //...

   <Button Content="{Binding ReadOnly}" Command="{Binding {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}, Path=DataContext.SelectChoice}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>

    // replace textbox by Button
    // ...

</ListBox>`

Comment: you can use this post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338657/listbox-of-buttons-and-relative-source`

Comment: Also, you should have a Converter on your MultiBinding